# Nodelist in DOM

Tags: html, dom, nodelist

Ok. I'm trying to get into the finer details regarding the DOM(document object module) and I seem to have situation.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div>Child 2</div>
    <div>Child 3</div>
    <div>Child 4</div>
    <div>Child 5</div>
    <div>Child 6</div>
</div>
```

Simple. 6 child div's nested in a parentDiv

Now i am accesing the elemts using this Javascript

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parentDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; ++i) {
  var item = parent[i]; 
  console.log(item);
}
```

So i run my program and I am expecting the console log to have 6 entries for my 6 div's. However i am seeing just one log entry which means that my Loop has an issue and is not reiterating.

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/WkdfB/)

Where am I going wrong. Isn't the nodelist like an array? If yes then why doesn't my loop work?

***EDIT:*** Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList and scroll to the **Example** . It says "*It's possible to loop over the items in a NodeList*". How can this be done

Comment: The function name clearly suggests: get elements by **class name**. Only one element in your example has the class name of `parentDiv`: the parent `<div>`.

Comment: Read the answers... :s

Comment: @shennan, Read my edit

Comment: I have to disagree on that one. CHeck this http://jsfiddle.net/WkdfB/1/

Comment: @AnaMaria Apologies, badly worded... The NodeList you're getting consists of one HTMLDivElement. Which means when you 'loop' through it, you only get one result. If you (instead) looked at my answer, you'd see that the NodeList would garner more results...

Comment: @shennan, Im sorry but your solution fiddles with the HTML too much. I think my question is clear. The parent div has 6 children. Then why is parent.lenth not returning 6?

Comment: @AnaMaria if you don't want to fiddle with the HTML too much then dig deeper into the DOM from within the loop as per appended suggestion. I can't be any clearer: the NodeList contains one element, because there is only one div with a class name of `parentDiv`.

Comment: Got your point. Currenly im gonna upvote you answer & benjamin. Hopefully somebody can give an alternative explanation. thanks for you help

Comment: @AnaMaria I'm unsure as to what alternative explanation there is. Forgive the frustration, but both mine and benjamin's answers are perfectly acceptable. What magic functionality are you looking for?

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `<div>` with the class `parentDiv`.

Change your HTML:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">Child 1</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Child 2</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Child 3</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Child 4</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Child 5</div>
    <div class="childDiv">Child 6</div>
</div>
```

And your JavaScript:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("childDiv");

for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; ++i) {
  var item = parent[i]; 
  console.log(item);
}
```

Be wary that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in some older browsers.

**Edit:**

The `NodeList` that you're trying to iterate over only has one element within it. Hence you only get one result. Either dig deeper into the DOM from within your loop, or leverage the use of class names for your child DOM Elements.

I presume there is a specific reason you're not using jQuery? Because it would be as simple as:

```
$('.parentDiv').children().each(function(){

    console.log(this);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all elements that contain the class name `"parentDiv"`, which is only your one parent item.  What you actually want are all the divs inside that parent.

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("parentDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; ++i) {
  var parent = parents[i]; 
  var children = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var j = 0; j < children.length; ++j) {
    var item = children[i];
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture the node list of elements following the parentDiv, you can use:

```
var parentNode = document.getElementsByClassName("parentDiv")[0];

var childNodesList = parentNode.getElementsByTagName( "div" );
```

It will fetch you all the div elements inside the parentDiv.

hope that helps.